# Accessing the current client app using Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I'm using [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) to manage client applications on a Rails-based API I'm building. I have a controller action in which I'd like to check some information about the client app that submitted the request which the action is handling.

Does Doorkeeper provide a helper or other easy way to access (in a controller) the Doorkeeper::Application that made the request being processed? I'm envisioning an analogue to Devise's 'current_user' method.

If no such helper exists, how can I get this information?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

And now I've figured it out.

Doorkeeper provides `doorkeeper_token`, which can be accessed in the controller. This is a `Doorkeeper::AccessToken` object, which references the app the token belongs to (as `doorkeeper_token.application`). This is referenced (in the example code) [here](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper#authenticated-resource-owner).

Comment: It looks like this answer may be outdated. I am not able to get `doorkeeper_token` or `doorkeeper_token.application` to work. It only returns `nil`.

Comment: Also have `nil` in `doorkeeper_token.application`. How to tell Doorkeeper to fill this field ?